# not lebesgue integrable function

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

i know that it is not lebesgue integrable. By definition, I have to sum first on all neg. parts and then on all positives. Is that correct?
$\int_{\pi}^{\infty}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx$

So I have now
$\int_{\pi}^a\frac{sin(x)}{x}dx=\frac{-cos(x)}{x}|_{\pi}^a+\int_{\pi}^a\frac{cos(x)}{x^2}dx$

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Are you planning to show that $\sin(x) /x$ is Lebesgue integrable over the positive real line using integration by parts or what?

Comment: not lebesque integrable, cause of the definition

Comment: So what is your question exactly?

Comment: how to do that, $f^{-}$ and then $f^{+}$

Comment: so it is riemann integrable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $d\mu(x) $ is used the Lebesgue integral and $dx$ is used for the Riemann integral.

Define $$g(x) =\frac{\sin(x) } {x} $$
We use The Monotone Convergence Theorem to link the Lebesgue integral with the Riemann integral, just use $g_n(x)=\mathbf{1}_{[\pi,n]}g^+(x)$ and get:
\begin{align}
\int_{[\pi,\infty)} g^+(x)\,d\mu(x)=\int^\infty_\pi g^+(x)\,dx
\end{align}
Moreover:
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_\pi g^+(x)\,dx&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \int^{(2k+1)\pi}_{2k\pi} \frac{\sin(x)}{x}\,dx\\
&\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{(2k+1)\pi}\int^{(2k+1)\pi}_{2k\pi} \sin(x)\,dx \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2}{(2k+1)\pi}\\
&=\infty
\end{align} Can you do the same for $g^-$ to finish the conclusion?

I have also another question for you, why by integration by parts looks that $g$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[\pi, \infty) $? Where is the problem?

Comment: i was wrong. First I will read the definitions again. Give me time, and thanks

Comment: if $g^{-}$ and $g^{+}$ are both $=\infty$ it is lebesque integrable? First I start with $g^{-}$. I have to start to sum all negative parts , for the proof. Is that right?

Comment: @Moira7777 actually if one of them is infinity then the function is not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: oh sorry, i wrote that out the first time I read it (on my papers). But then someone told me something else so I was so confused. Thank you for your help I got it now.

Comment: Good to hear that!